# Do suspended users see when they are suspended and how long they are suspended?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Do suspended users see the *This account is temporarily suspended.* message other users see? Do they also see when the suspension ends?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, timed-suspension messages are visible to all users of the site.

Comment: Thank you for the reply; I didn't want to become a suspended user just to be able to know if suspended users can see the suspension message.